# apache2 cannot access directory - permission denied

Tags: php, apache, apache2, ubuntu-16.04

I have profile.php where user can upload a profile picture. However I keep getting these two errors

```
-"PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(uploads/profile_picture/1545865742_WP_000002.jpg): failed to open stream: Per$" and 
-"PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpDKNvXM' to 'uploads/profile_picture/1545865742_WP_$"
```

result of `ps aux | grep apache2` and  `ps aux | grep httpd` is

```
ubuntu   10958  0.0  0.0  12944   984 pts/1    S+   23:24   0:00 grep --color=auto apache2
```

so I changed the owner of both directories (temp and target) to `ubuntu`:

```
sudo chown -R ubuntu /var/www/html/login/uploads/profile_picture
sudo chown -R ubuntu /tmp
```

I am still getting those two errors. what could be the issue?

Comment: Both your errors seem to have been truncated - can you please post the full error text. Also, your `chown` is probably a bad idea - `sudo chmod a+w` might be better?

Comment: I only removed date and time, PID and useless details from the errors. I also tried sudo chmod a+w and a+wr but still getting the same errors

Answer (score 0):

issue was with /tmp directory. I did all permissions on this directory but I was still getting those errors.
I end up editing php.ini and uncommented upload_tmp_dir and set it to /var/www/html and everything working fine now.